# Is it possible to customize scoring in Azure Cognitive Search when using semantic search mode, particularly for newer documents?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Is there a way to boost Azure Cognitive Search scoring (specifically looking to boost more recent documents) when in semantic search mode?   It appears to me that you can boost with it off, but once turned on you lose this.

We've added a custom scoring profile, and it works really well with semantic off.   In general we get better results with semantic on, however we then lose the custom scoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, scoring profile only applies to the "retrieval" phase. The scoring profiles helps rank all matching documents using your configured weights. The top 50 documents out of that list get reranked using our semantic model using linguistic properties only (ignoring the configured weight). We are looking  into incorporating scoring profiles into the semantic feature, but don't have an actual date for this feature yet. If you have specific needs as to how you would want the scoring profiles to interact with your semantic configuration, please share them as it would help us define the requirements for this feature. Thank you

Comment: Thank you!   for me its really just a way to score semantically but boost freshness.  I suppose we can do this with another pass of the data perhaps.

Comment: Do you perhaps know of azure profiler and can take a look at this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76383539/azure-profiler-session-does-not-appear-in-app-insight/