# Azure profiler session does not appear in app insight

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-application-insights

I got a .net6 service hosted in an AKS cluster with app insight and profiler enabled. Logs appear in app insight and live metrics are working and I can see every action in app insight.

When I click the "Profile now" button in the performance tab, it says a profiling session is in progress and I fire a few requests. Eventually I get a message in app insight of a timeout and no session is added to the list. Why could it happen?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, Azure profiler just does not support dotnet 6. There might be other solutions for Azure witr this dotnet version

Answer (score 0):

> Profiler is supported on the [.NET Framework later than version 4.6.2](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework) as  mentioned in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-monitor/app-insights/profiler-troubleshooting#make-sure-your-app-runs-on-right-version).

***Need to check below:***

1. Check the timeframe when you are using the **"Azure Profiler"**. Because if you try to look at telemetry information or logs that are more than a few months old, you will receive session timeout issues. ***Sometimes, Traces are  removed after seven days.***
2. Moreover, Profiler stops working if there are no records to be displayed. Check that the profiler session is properly enabled. To avoid conflicts, disable and re-enable it.
3. Check the status of the Application insights profiler with the help of `kudu console` by visiting to `Advanced Tools` option in the app service.

   *Path:* `Web App -> Development Tools -> Go to kudu console -> Click on Web Jobs`

[image]

4. Furthermore, if Profiler has a high number of active sessions and an excessive amount of traffic, it may generate these kinds of issues. Profiler can be enabled on at most of four Web Apps operating under the same service plan. Cross check and perform the operations.

*Note:* After enabled the profiler, try to send/receive a short amount of data initially. There will be a conflict if you send a huge data in a single attempt at the initial stages.
If still the issue persists, refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-monitor/app-insights/profiler-troubleshooting) for the relevant performance issues of the Profiler sessions.

I've tried the same in my environment by deploying a `.NET 6` web app and enabled the profiler session with the application insights of that specific web app. Once I triggered the event, the profiling session prompted with the *"profiling completed"* message and shown the profile information as below.

[image]

You can also check whether the profiler is running, by going into `Web jobs` of the `web app` blade. Check the logs for the detailed profiling status.

*Path:* `Goto Web app -> Settings -> WebJobs`.

[image]

**Alternatively,** *Check the web app down status as well as the availability and performance status of the Web app linked to application insights. If the web application has any of the flaws listed above, it will not correctly trace the logs and leads to session time out issues.*

[image]

Comment: I'm not using a web app but a service inside an AKS cluster. This specific usage in my question is a local cluster on my machine so I can't use anything you wrote about web apps. Since it's only me testing, there isn't almost any traffic at all besides my 2-3 requests im sending when pressing the "Profile now" button. Also, everything I do is being picked in app insight in the performance tab, but nothing is created in the profiler

Comment: Ok understood the concern. If it is in AKS cluster, it is not supported. And you need to use the external profiling tools for profiling the telemetry data. @CodeMonkey

Comment: But according to MS documentation, Kubernetes is supported for .NET core as seen here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/profiler/profiler-overview#supported-in-profiler

Comment: It is supported for .NET core framework as mentioned in MSDoc. @CodeMonkey

Comment: And I'm using .net 6 which is also considered part of the .net core group (I know that ".net core" is a previous version to .net 6 up until 3.1 i think, but 6 is considered as "core" as its a version later than .net fw)

Comment: BTW, this is the example with instructions which I tried following and it even says its targeting .net 6 specifically: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/profiler/profiler-containers?tabs=net-core-new

Comment: So it seems like you don't know the answer?

Comment: I am trying to explore more on this concern. Will update the answer shortly.

Comment: Not yet found any accurate solutions rather than the above.

Comment: Well the above is not a solution at all for this question since I do click the profile button but get the error message listed in the question. Besides that, app insight is working and logging events from the service

Comment: Found anything? seems like a lot to find

Comment: we are still waiting for your response

Comment: I was engaged with some other concepts. I will check and let you know if I find anything related to it. @CodeMonkey